# RecyclerView in RecyclerView is laggy

Tags: java, android, kotlin

I have a Model as follows

```
data class PhotoDate(
var date: String,
var listPhoto: List<PhotoModel>? = arrayListOf()
```

)

It will correspond to a List(PhotoDate), and I display it in a RecyclerView and List(PhotoModel) I will display in a child RecyclerView

However, when there are too many photos, scrolling will lag, what should I do to be able to swipe smoothly? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution, we should use VIEW_TYPE in RecyclerView